# DrawerLayout lagging while sliding / scrolling due to icon images displaying

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin.android, drawerlayout

Inside my activity I have a DrawerLayout . Its drawer's ListView is populated using the MenuLVAdapter from below . There are only 5 items in the list . The individual items' layout consists of a horizontal LinearLayout containing one ImageView on the left and one TextView on the right . The options' names are within a string array resource, and the icons are drawable resources . Each drawable is an 128x128 transparent background png , about 7KB each .

The problem is that while I am sliding the drawer , the animation is very choppy when the device renders the icons . Until then , the drawer slides as it should . The same choppyness occours both when opening / closing the drawer and when scrolling . Without the custom images (using the stock @android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery icon) , there is no lag what-so-ever .

I have only tested this on a WVGA hTC Desire X packing a Dual Core 1GHz CPU & 768MB RAM . I believe I might need to resize the images and make them smaller , but I'm not sure what the proper sizes should be . My app also has an activity packing a ListView with an almost identic layout , the icons being 256x256 transparent pngs . That one works like a charm - the only difference is that it's not a drawerlayout and that the image is the same for each item . I've also noticed that making the ImageView inside the drawer's ListView bigger makes it even laggyer .

I've tried a couple of things , from setting the images as drawables or bitmaps instead , having the views declared global and only loaded once with FindViewById , enabled / disabled scrolling cache and persistent drawing cache on the drawer's ListView , but none of these had any effect at all .

What should I do to get rid of the lag?

Here's the adapter for the ListView (note : I've disabled the custom typeface loading , still not working) :

```
class MenuLVAdapter : BaseAdapter
{
    string[] items;
    int[] images =
    {
        Resource.Drawable.dash_menuicon_home,
        Resource.Drawable.dash_menuicon_mydashers,
        Resource.Drawable.dash_menuicon_history,
        Resource.Drawable.dash_menuicon_settings,
        Resource.Drawable.dash_menuicon_exit
    };

    Activity context;

    public MenuLVAdapter(Activity context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        items = context.Resources.GetStringArray(Resource.Array.menuLVArray);
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public override Java.Lang.Object GetItem(int position)
    {
        return items[position];
    }

    public string[] Items
    {
        get { return items; }
    }

    public override int Count
    {
        get { return items.Length; }
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View view = convertView ?? context.LayoutInflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.MenuLVLayout, null); // re-use an existing view, if one is available
        TextView menuItemNameTV = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.menuItemName);
        ImageView menuItemIconIV = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.menuItemIcon);
        menuItemNameTV.Text = items[position];
        menuItemIconIV.SetImageResource(images[position]);
        Typeface erasMid = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(context.Assets, "Fonts/ERASM.TTF");
        menuItemNameTV.SetTypeface(erasMid, TypefaceStyle.Normal);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Also here's my MenuLVLayout.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp">
    <ImageView
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:id="@+id/menuItemIcon" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/menuItemName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="9.3dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: what's the resolution of ic_menu_gallery? Have you made graphics for each screen resolution (mdpi - xxhdpi)?

Comment: I don't know the resolution of ic_menu_gallery , it's from the stock Android resources . And no , I haven't made graphics for each screen resolution . Would that help? Since the current size is pretty low (128x128) , compared to the standard for my mdpi (72x72) , I don't see why it would be that much of a problem .

Comment: Your graphics are fine and shouldn't be a problem. You might want to check out [Hierarchy Viewer](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/hierarchy-viewer.html) or the  Dump View Hierarchy function in DDMS in Eclipse to see if there are overly complicated ways your view hierarchy is organized

Answer (score 0):

I've kinda managed to fix this by creating custom icons for each screen density using Android Asset studio . Now there seems to be no lag at all . The downside of this is that I have to redo all the icons if I may want to change their size .

For those who are having the same problem and / or want to know how I fixed it , go to [Android Asset Studio](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html) & choose "Generic Icons" . After that , load an icon and make sure you set the "Size" parameter to the desired icon size in DP (in my case 35dp , as seen on the item layout) . You can mess around with the other settings as well if you'd like , but this is the important step . Now all you have to do is load your icons one by one and download the zip for each one . All the settings except the name will remain the same if you just load a new file without refreshing the page - that helps speed up the process . Also , as I've said , if you'll ever want to change the size , be sure to have the original files backed up , because you will have to repeat this process .